# IdentityServer4 get access token

Tags: c#, .net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.0

Is it possible to get generated access token from `IExtensionGrantValidator` or `ICustomTokenRequestValidator` implementations or I must implement another validator? I can't find any properties from which I can get access token.

Comment: What are you trying to do? In what context are you trying to retrieve the token?

Comment: @ChrisPratt I have two scenarios: 1. I send web request to token endpoint, where I give to client some additional claims, 2. I redirect from site to IS4 login page, where I authenticate and redirect back to site. In both cases I need to log generated access tokens. I can't find any information how access tokens could be obtained.

Answer (score 0):

Well, within the context of retrieving it initially from IdentityServer, the token is in the `AccessToken` property of the `TokenResponse` instance returned.

From within an ASP.NET Core application authenticating via IdentityServer, the fact that it came from IdentityServer is inconsequential. Generically, to retrieve an access token, you'd use:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;

...

var token = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
```

Comment: `AccessToken` property can be used only on client. `await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");` always return null in my context.

Comment: @developer if you are getting null then there must be something wrong in the client configuration. What authentication middleware you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround, deps: IdentityServer4.AccessToken Validation 2.7 + IdentityModel 3.10

```
    services.AddScoped(provider =>
                {
                    var httpService = provider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();

                    var token = httpService.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"][0].Remove(0, "Bearer ".Length);
                    var userGuid = Guid.Parse(httpService.HttpContext.User.FindFirst("sub").Value);

                    // Use token 

                });
```